# Efficient histogram implementation using a hash function

Tags: c, algorithm, search, lookup

Is there a more efficient approach to computing a histogram than a binary search for a non-linear bin distribution?

I'm actually only interested in the bit of the algorithm that matches the key (value) to the bin (the transfer function?) , i.e. for a bunch of floating point values I just want to know the appropriate bin index for each value.

I know that for a linear bin distribution you can get O(1) by dividing the value by the bin width, and that for non linear bins a binary search gets you O(logN). My current implementation uses a binary search on unequal bin widths.

In the spirit of improving efficiency I was curious as to whether you could use a hash function to map a value to its appropriate bin and achieve O(1) time complexity when you have bins of unequal widths?

Comment: It is theoretically impossible (in a general case). If it is possible, then searching for a number in a sorted list becomes O(1).

Comment: yes i think you're right, the thing with a hash fn is you just want to compute a value from a key and hope its reasonably unique, i'm asking for the hash fn to map to a specific bin value - that would need a ridiculously complex hash fn to implement. so to summarise the answer is no you can't use a hash fn for this purpose

Comment: @ElKamina In general, you can do more to numbers than just compare them.

Comment: @rrenaud Just show me how you can do it with O(1) for general case and you win

Comment: @ElKamina There are complexities between O(1) and O(log(n)).  For example, Van Emde Boas trees support searching for an m bit integer (usually m = log(n)) in O(log(m)) time.  You can sort ints faster than O(n log (n)).

Comment: i can trade time for space by opting to have (a far greater no. of) equal sized bins, then i do get O(1) but not necessarily quicker as i then have to sum the values in those bins (of which i will typically have 1000's more with equal rather than unequal bin-widths). Unfortunately no free lunch here i suspect

Comment: @ElKamina: I don't think its theoretically impossible to construct a (hash) fn, f(x) that could map x values to the correct bin index - but for an arbitrary distribution of unequal bin-widths I certainly think it would be practically impossible, and much slower to compute than the alternative binary search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordinary hash functions are intended to scatter different values quite randomly across some range.  A single-bit difference in arguments may lead to dozens of bits different in results.  For that reason, ordinary hash functions are not suitable for the situation described in the question.

An alternative is to build an array P with entries that index into the table B of bin limits.  Given some value x, we find the bin `j` it belongs to (or sometimes a nearby bin) via `j = P[⌊x·r⌋]` where `r` is a ratio that depends on the size of P and the maximum value in B.  The effectiveness of this approach depends on the values in B and the size of P.

The behavior of functions like `P[⌊x·r⌋]` can be seen via the python code shown below.  (The method is about the same in any programming language.  However, tips for Python-to-C are given below.)  Suppose the code is stored in file histobins.py and loaded into the ipython interpreter with the command `import histobins as hb`.  Then a command like `hb.betterparts(27, 99, 9, 80,155)` produces output like

```
At  80 parts, steps = 20 =  7+13
At  81 parts, steps = 16 =  7+9
At  86 parts, steps = 14 =  6+8
At  97 parts, steps = 13 =  12+1
At 108 parts, steps = 12 =  3+9
At 109 parts, steps = 12 =  8+4
At 118 parts, steps = 12 =  6+6
At 119 parts, steps = 10 =  7+3
At 122 parts, steps = 10 =  3+7
At 141 parts, steps = 10 =  5+5
At 142 parts, steps = 10 =  4+6
At 143 parts, steps = 9 =  7+2
```

These parameters to betterparts set `nbins=27, topsize=99, seed=9, plo=80, phi=155` which creates a test set of 27 bins for values from 0 to 99, with random seed 9, and size of P from 80 to 155-1.  The number of “steps” is the number of times the two while loops in testparts() operated during a test with 10*nbins values from 0 to topsize.  Eg, “At 143 parts, steps = 9 =  7+2”  means that when the size of P is 143, out of 270 trials, 261 times `P[⌊x·r⌋]` produced the correct index at once; 7 times the index had to be decreased, and twice it had to be increased.

The general idea of the method is to trade off space for time.  Another tradeoff is preparation time versus operation time.  If you are going to be doing billions of lookups, it is worthwhile to do a few thousand trials to find a good value of |P|, the size of P.  If you are going to be doing only a few millions of lookups, it might be better to just pick some large value of |P| and run with it, or perhaps just run betterparts over a narrow range.  Instead of doing 75 tests as above, if we start with larger |P| fewer tests may give a good enough result.  For example, 10 tests via  “hb.betterparts(27, 99, 9, 190,200)” produces

```
At 190 parts, steps = 11 =  5+6
At 191 parts, steps = 5 =  3+2
At 196 parts, steps = 5 =  4+1
```

As long as P fits into some level of cache (along with other relevant data) making |P| larger will speed up access.  So, making |P| as large as practical is a good idea.  As |P| gets larger, the difference in performance between one value of |P| and the next gets smaller and smaller.  The limiting factors on speed then include time to multiply and time to set up while loops.  One approach for faster multiplies may be to choose a power of 2 as a multiplier; compute |P| to match; then use shifts or adds to exponents instead of multiplies.  One approach to spending less time setting up while loops is to move the statement `if bins[bin] <= x < bins[bin+1]:` (or its C equivalent, see below) to before the while statements and do the while's only if the `if` statement fails.

Python code is shown below.  Note, in translating from Python to C,
• # begins a comment
• `def` begins a function
• a statement like `ntest, right, wrong, x = 10*nbins, 0, 0, 0` assigns values to respective identifiers
• a statement like `return (ntest, right, wrong, stepdown, stepup)` returns a tuple of 5 values that the caller can assign to a tuple or to respective identifiers
• the scope of a `def, while,` or `if` ends with a line not indented farther than the `def, while,` or `if`
• `bins = [0]` initializes a list (an extendible indexable array) with value `0` as its initial entry
• `bins.append(t)` appends value t at the end of list `bins`
• `for i,j in enumerate(p):` runs a loop over the elements of iterable p (in this case, p is a list), making the index `i` and corresponding entry `j == p[i]` available inside the loop
• `range(nparts)` stands for a list of the values 0, 1, ... nparts-1
• `range(plo, phi)` stands for a list of the values plo, plo+1, ... phi-1
• `if bins[bin] <= x < bins[bin+1]` means `if ((bins[bin] <= x) && (x < bins[bin+1]))`
• `int(round(x*float(nparts)/topsize)))` actually rounds `x·r`, instead of computing `⌊x·r⌋` as advertised above

```
def makebins(nbins, topsize):
    bins, t = [0], 0
    for i in range(nbins):
        t += random.random()
        bins.append(t)
    for i in range(nbins+1):
        bins[i] *= topsize/t
    bins.append(topsize+1)
    return bins
#________________________________________________________________
def showbins(bins):
    print ''.join('{:6.2f} '.format(x) for x in bins)
def showparts(nbins, bins, topsize, nparts, p):
    ratio = float(topsize)/nparts
    for i,j in enumerate(p):
        print '{:3d}. {:3d} {:6.2f} {:7.2f} '.format(i, j, bins[j], i*ratio)
    print 'nbins: {}  topsize: {}  nparts: {}  ratio: {}'.format(nbins, topsize, nparts, ratio)
    print 'p = ', p
    print 'bins = ',
    showbins(bins)
#________________________________________________________________

def testparts(nbins, topsize, nparts, seed):
    # Make bins and make lookup table p
    import random
    if seed > 0: random.seed(seed)
    bins = makebins(nbins,topsize)
    ratio, j, p = float(topsize)/nparts, 0, range(nparts)
    for i in range(nparts):
        while j<nbins and i*ratio >= bins[j+1]:
            j += 1
        p[i] = j
    p.append(j)
    #showparts(nbins, bins, topsize, nparts, p)

    # Count # of hits and steps with avg. of 10 items per bin
    ntest, right, wrong, x  = 10*nbins, 0, 0, 0
    delta, stepdown, stepup = topsize/float(ntest), 0, 0
    for i in range(ntest):
        bin = p[min(nparts, max(0, int(round(x*float(nparts)/topsize))))]

        while bin < nbins and x >= bins[bin+1]:
            bin += 1; stepup += 1
        while bin > 0 and x < bins[bin]:
            bin -= 1; stepdown += 1
        if bins[bin] <= x < bins[bin+1]: # Test if bin is correct
            right += 1
        else:
            wrong += 1
            print 'Wrong bin {} {:7.3f} at x={:7.3f}   Too {}'.format(bin, bins[bin], x, 'high' if bins[bin] > x else 'low')
        x += delta
    return (ntest, right, wrong, stepdown, stepup)
#________________________________________________________________

def betterparts(nbins, topsize, seed, plo, phi):
    beststep = 1e9
    for parts in range(plo, phi):
        ntest, right, wrong, stepdown, stepup = testparts(nbins, topsize, parts, seed)
        if wrong: print 'Error with ', parts, ' parts'
        steps = stepdown + stepup
        if steps <= beststep:
            beststep = steps
            print 'At {:3d} parts, steps = {:d} =  {:d}+{:d}'.format(parts, steps, stepdown, stepup)
#________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: is this an implementation of interpolation sort? this bit, P[⌊x·r⌋], looks like an interpolation sort (btw what are those half square brackets? i can't even type them let alone know what they mean)

Comment: having read the code a bit more carefully i would say this is a linear interpolation 'best-guess' followed by a linear search if it doesn't get it right

Comment: ⌊x⌋ stands for floor(x), and ⌈x⌉ would stand for ceil(x).  Using floor or ceil of x·r might get rid of one of the while loops.  One *might* think of this as an interpolation-via-table-lookup method.  If you uncomment the `showparts(...)` call in `testparts()` and run (eg) `hb.testparts(11, 99, 17, 1)` you can see the contents of p[] and get an idea of how it works.  Also, the linear search part rarely run more than one pass, and (if nparts is big enough) most often runs no passes.

Answer (score 3):

In some simple cases you can get O(1).

Suppose, your values are 8-bit, from 0 to 255.

If you split them into 8 bins of sizes 2, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, then the bin value ranges will be: 0-1, 2-3, 4-7, 8-15, 16-31, 32-63, 64-127, 128-255.

In binary these ranges look like:

```
0000000x (bin 0)
0000001x
000001xx
00001xxx
0001xxxx
001xxxxx
01xxxxxx
1xxxxxxx (bin 7)
```

So, if you can quickly (in O(1)) count how many most significant zero bits there are in the value, you can get the bin number from it.

In this particular case you may precalculate a look-up table of 256 elements, containing the bin number and finding the appropriate bin for a value is just one table look-up.

Actually, with 8-bit values you can use bins of arbitrary sizes since the look-up table is small.

If you were to go with bins of sizes of powers of 2, you could reuse this look-up table for 16-bit values as well. And you'd need two look-ups. You can extend it to even longer values.

Answer (score 2):

[Interpolation search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search) is your friend.  It's kind of an optimistic, predictive binary search where it guesses where the bin should be based on a linear assumption about the distribution of inputs, rather than just splitting the search space in half at each step.  It will be O(1) if the linear assumption is true, but still works (though more slowly) when the assumption is not.  To the degree that its predictions are accurate, the search is fast.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the implementation of the hashing and the type of data you're working with. For smaller data sets a more simple algorithm like binary search might outperform constant lookup if the lookup-overhead of hashing is larger on average.
The usual implementation of hashing, consists of an array of linked lists and a hashing function that maps a string to an index in the array of linked lists. There's a thing called the load factor, which is the number of elements in the hash map / length of the linked-list array. Thus for load factors < 1 you'll achieve constant lookup in the best case because no linked-list will contain more than one element (best case).

There's only one way to find out which is better - implement a hash map and see for yourself. You should be able to get something near constant lookup :)

Comment: I'm not actually worried about the load factor as I don't need a hash-table just the hash function to get me from value to bin